# Correlation in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

If we have dynamic values in JMeter, in Response Body, Response Headers, and Request Headers, then we can correlate using Post Processors. But If we have dynamic values in the Request Body, then how can we correlate.

Could anybody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Where do these "dynamic values" come from?

- If you need to populate them with the data from the response - [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) approach applies
- If you need to populate them from external sources - it's called [parameterization](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/), the most commonly used approach is [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- If you need to provide random/unique values - look at [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Comment: Need to provide the random/unique values in the post request. which JMeter Function we can use. And the dynamic value length is huge